# Symfony Composer Install - Command "app" is not defined

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I've just inherited a bunch of php apps built with Symfony2 from a former colleague. I'm struggling to get them going, but feel like I've very close.

I'm using Composer to install the vendor/ and bin/ directories using `composer install`. I've deleted (really renamed) the original composer.lock file, because he had some paths for bundles using his local machine's directory.

Running `composer install` gets me all the way to the end of the composer.json file and then it starts to "Writing lock file" I get an `Command "app" is not defined` error. What's up with that? I can't run the the `php app/console server:run` or anything else, because essentially I have yet to create a bootstrap.php.cache file.

I feel like I'm so close! Has anyone run into this before? Below is the output I'm getting from the console. I've still very new to Symfony and really appreciate any help!

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files



  [InvalidArgumentException]     
  Command "app" is not defined.  



Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                     
  An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.
```

Updated with composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" },
        "files": [
            "vendor/tobie/ua-parser/php/bin/uaparser.php",
            "vendor/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php"
        ]
    },

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "ssh://git@sourcecode.ts.vcu.edu:22/~git/vcu-cas-bundle.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.*@dev",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "dev-master",
        "vcu/cas-bundle": "dev-master",
        "tobie/ua-parser": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your composer.json.

Comment: @LaurentG, I've updated the post with my composer.json file. Thank you so much for helping me solve this!

Comment: could you please run "composer self-update" and try it again ?

Comment: You said that it used to be on a different machine.  Can you make sure the app and web directories exist on your machine?

Comment: @johnSmith now running the `composer self-update` I get the following [ErrorException] which I'm not sure about how to fix...

ErrorException]                                                                                           
  rename(/Users/samuelyerkes/.composer/cache/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Permission denied

Comment: Just a general suggestion here.  Consider going to the Symfony 2 download site and installing a plain copy of S2.3.  composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.3.*".  Mess around with a bit to see how the directory structure works and how to run app/console.  At that point you can then start adding lines from your composer.json file and see what happens.  As it is, you seem to be trying to learn S2 by looking at someone else's code.  And that can be challenging.

Comment: @Moose sry i forgot, run this command as superuser

Comment: @johnSmith, Thanks, I've verified I'm running the newest version of composer. 

Still getting this error that I can't generate the bootstrap file because the `Command "app" is not defined`